# SQL Visual Studio - Use Parameter in Query Calculation

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012

In my SQL Visual Studio report I have a parameter to request a percentage from the user.  I would like to take the number they enter and use in a calculation to filter records.

Example:  `percentage entered 80 (@Pct)`

In my query designer I want to multiply the field "`Capacity`" by `@Pct` and then only show records "`NbrItems`" that are `=>` to that capacity.

I am able to do this if I hard code the percentage but I do not know how to make the percentage a variable amount.

Comment: "SQL Visual Studio report"...what is this?

Comment: Did you try this?   https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=use+parameter+in+SSRS+query

Answer (score 0):

Why You Are Not Using Like,

```
Select * from Table_Name Where NbrItems >= (Capacity * (@Pct / 100.0))
```

Comment: It should be `(Capacity * (@Pct / 100.0))`, as the value would be `80`. The division by 100 converts it to `0.80`, which is the proper way to calculate percentages.

Comment: Is there a scenario in which these two formulas would produce different results?

Comment: No I'm asking how could `(Capacity*@Pct/100)` produce a different results from `Capacity * (@Pct / 100)`

Comment: ohho, Actually My answer was `Where NbrItems>=(Capacity*@Pct)` and @KEN point this out that i missed divide by 100(NbrItems>=(Capacity*@Pct/100)`.
sorry :)

Comment: @عجمان : Probably not. I tend to just include the parentheses to make sure of precedence of operations (and to make it clear later what my intent was, when I (or someone else) looks at it a year from now). It's also why I used `100.0` and not just `100` - I wanted to make it clear that I expected a floating point division and not integer.